# Combining two RC time delay circuits to generate both LOW and HIGH pulses with two push buttons

Tags: circuit-design, 555, delay

I have come up with the following circuit that can be used to momentarily generate either a LOW or HIGH pulse based on what push button is pressed.

Can you please tell me if there is any issues with it?  Can I apply improvements or simplifications to my circuit?  I feel like these two can be somehow combined into a single circuit, but I'm not sure how.

[image: circuit that allows generation of a short pulse using push button, capacitor, resistor and diode]

The intention is to make sure that if I press **SW-ON**, the voltage at `OUT` temporary goes all the way down to 0V. If I press **SW-OFF**, the the voltage temporary goes all the way up to VCC, which is about 12V DC.

(Note that the voltage at `OUT` is kept at about ½ of the VCC using a voltage divider, see below)

---

P.S. This circuit is used as part of a NE555 bi-stable latch that allows a single button to toggle between the ON and OFF states.

[image: NE555 Bi-stable toggle push button to control a relay as latch circuit]

As you can see above, the **Trigger** and **Threshold** pins are tied together and go to the voltage divider (two 10KΩ), and then goes to the net name `SW`.  The wire named `OUT` in the first picture is directly connected to the `SW` net.

A small note regarding the RESET is that it's being used to receive an exclusive **reset** signal from another chip, so I don't want to use it here as an OFF signal.  The `100nF` cap is used to keep the initial state during powering up to be OFF as well.

---

Lastly, I'm aware of some other alternatives of doing what I want which are better. However, I want to learn about the potential flaws in my circuit design so I appreciate it if you could please help me in that regard.

Comment: Why don't you use a circuit simulator to try the ideas out?

Comment: I attempted to use some that I found online but I couldn't quite figure out how to use them. I have no offline simulations tools, so currently I'm testing these on a breadboard.

Comment: @Andyaka Additionally I don't think I can learn from just using a simulator, rather I'm looking for others' experience on designing simple circuits such as these. I appreciate the thought, though.

Comment: Everyone's using them and, they are a godsend to anyone interested in circuit design despite the learning curve. Not understanding how to use one does not logically permit you to dismiss them as inapplicable to learning.

Comment: @Andyaka Even though it might be against the rules, but I appreciate if you could suggest one or some that might be suitable in my case so I can try those as well. Thanks.

Comment: I use micro-cap. It's still available as a free download (if you know where to look) and has a large number of component libraries. Others use LTSpice.

Comment: This conversation was [automatically moved to the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148995/discussion-between-david-refoua-and-andy-aka). Thanks, I'll try both and see if it helps. 

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about your design - it is too complicated for this simple task. Also it does not solve a basic problem which is de-bouncing. You need just a 2x Schmitt-Trigger inverters and resistor + capacitor. The circuit is just an example. A pulse source is your switch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. Does this work based on the propagation delay, or is there some other reason to chain two Schmitt-Triggers?

Comment: Also, can you please explain why the caps in my circuit doesn't solve de-bouncing? I ask this because in my tests it seemed to work correctly.

Comment: Yes! you will take one, a positive pulse after the first gate, than a second one after the second gate. Your circuit generates both pulses at the same time from same output - that's probably not what are looking for? Listen to @Andy aka - use an LTSpice or other simulation software. Also, I don't understand why don't you make this thing on a breadboard and probe it with a scope?

Comment: What test? Did you probe your circuit with a scope?

Comment: While the RC filter smooths out rapid voltage changes, it doesn't have the distinct hysteresis thresholds of a Schmitt trigger. Thus, the RC circuit might be more susceptible to noise, especially if the noise amplitude is close to the voltage level being read as a digital transition. Because you're relying on the RC time constant to filter out bounces, there's often a trade-off between filtering effectiveness and response time. If the RC time constant is too long, the circuit might respond slowly to legitimate switch transitions.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit gives you a trigger pulse of all supply range.
With 1uF it has a time constant 100ms.
If you want another pulse width just change capacitor.
A diode just quick discharges the cap when button is released.
A diode also clamps the output voltage to -0.7V during cap discharge otherwise the output voltage goes negative to about -10V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwzZOO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Combined version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzqZYa.png)</sup>